# LibreOffice Writer can't keep graphic lines in one place

Tags: graphics, libreoffice

I have a docx document that originally had few separate lines drawn forming a frame. Whenever I try to edit anything in the document and save it, all the vertical lines disappear after opening the document again. I tried to draw new lines myself using the drawing tool, but after I open the same document again, the new vertical lines are always in wrong places, they just can't stay put. Is there anyway to prevent the original lines from disappearing or at least be able to draw new ones that will still be where they are supposed to be after reopening the document?

Comment: Can you show examples?

Comment: Unfortunately, the document is private.